# Formatting issues with table image

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

So the main issues I am having with the table is coloring it completely in ('#EEECE1') color and formatting it so that there is no white area around it. This way, I can easily insert it into a ppt. doc. without it looking off with the border and extra space.

I have the following code:

```
def tables():
    data=[[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]]
    fig= plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.axis('off')
    rows=['AB','BC','SK','MB']
    cols=["Gas", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Oil", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Bit", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Total", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Hor", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Vert/Dir", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr"]
    table = ax.table(cellText=data, colLabels=cols,rowLabels=rows, loc='upper center',cellLoc='center')
    table.auto_set_font_size(True)
    table.scale(1.5,1.5)
    plt.savefig(filenameTemplate2, format='png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the axes. You have a big white axis area around your table, and the png is created with tight borders around the axis, not the table. Removing the axis background colour helps a bit:

```
ax.set_axisbgcolor((0,0,0,0))
```

gets you transparent graph area. The point with a transparent bg is that it should stay transparent in PPT as well. Another way to specify the transparency is when you create the subplot:

```
add_subplot(111, axisbg='none')
```

Then you will also have to adjust the axis position relative to the figure, for example:

```
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

to fill the whole figure.

The cell colours can be set when creating the table, but it seems to be a bit clumsy:

```
tbl=plt.table(cellText=data, cellColours=[["#EEECE1"] * len(data[0])]*len(data))
```

**N.B.** At least my matplotlib is buggy here, see the end of the answer.

---

So, something along these lines:

```
data=[[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='none')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
rows=['AB','BC','SK','MB']
cols=["Gas", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Oil", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Bit", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Total", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Hor", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Vert/Dir", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr"]
table = ax.table(cellText=data, colLabels=cols, rowLabels=rows, rowColours=['none']*len(data), colColours=['none']*len(data[0]), loc='upper center',cellLoc='center', cellColours=[["none"] * len(data[0])] * len(data))
table.auto_set_font_size(True)
table.scale(1.5, 1.5)
plt.savefig("test.png", format='png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

This should produce a table with fully transparent background. If you want to have background colour for the cells, change the "none" in cellColours. Kw args `rowColours` and `colColours` determine the colours behind the column and row labels. If you want to set the background for the whole image, change it in the `axisbg` argument of `add_subplot`.

And be warned: it seems that different versions of matplotlib do a bit different things with the scaling.

UPDATE: There may be a bug in `table.py` in factory function `table`... It seems that if both `colColors` and `colLabels` are defined, the cell offset is 0, and the rows jump to a wrong place.

The workaround is an ugly hack, but:

```
table = ax.table(cellText=data, colLabels=cols, rowLabels=rows, loc='upper center',cellLoc='center')
for cidx in table._cells:
    table._cells[cidx].set_facecolor('none')
```

will do. `table._cells` is a dictionary of cells (which are built on the `Rectangle` class). The same trick enables you to do whatever fancy colouring for the cell faces or edges, and the dict keys are cell coordinates.

Comment: Just now trying to set the column/row widths. What is the syntax for doing that in table?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems going on here:

The first is that although you have `ax.axes('off`), this just turns off the drawing of the lines and labels in the axes, but doesn't remove the axes, and this is causing all the white space below the table.  To solve this, I don't know how completely turn off the drawing of the axes, but a kludge is the make the aspect ration smaller than the table, and then expand the table but the same ratio (see example below).

For the colors, it needs to be kept in mind: 1) that the axes color and figure color are different (eg, in the usual gui display, the figure color is gray and axes are white); 2) the figure color in saved figures is different than the displayed figures, and this needs to be set directly in `savefig`.

Finally, you might want to use transparency here, rather than the color you specifically asked for (eg, in `savefig` set the keyword `transparent=True`), but this depends a bit on what you're doing with the figure afterwards, and whether transparency is supported, so I'll just answer the question about colors that way you asked it.

Here's the figure and code:

[image]

```
data=[[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],[10,10,10,5,5,5,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_aspect(.1)
rows=['AB','BC','SK','MB']
cols=["Gas", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Oil", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Bit", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Total", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Hor", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr","Vert/Dir", "Wk/Wk", "Yr/Yr"]
table = ax.table(cellText=data, colLabels=cols,rowLabels=rows, loc='upper center',cellLoc='center')
table.auto_set_font_size(True)
table.scale(1.5,15.)
plt.savefig("test.png", format='png',bbox_inches='tight', facecolor='#EEECE1', transparent=True)
```

Comment: This answer is producing the result I am looking for but I would like to set the color of the table itself, rather than the background of the figure that I am saving. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `.set_backgroundcolor('#EEECE1')` you may need to set it on table, ax or fig.